# How to troubleshoot a jump in CPU load?

Tags: linux, memory, central-processing-unit

If monitoring shows a jump in CPU load on your main production server and the box is slow to respond, what actions should I take? What commands should I run or how do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install process accounting package if you have kernel supporting process accounting.
Later on with commands like lastcomm, sa, or atop you can check what is/was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Run the <kbd>top</kbd> command.

Comment: And `ps` and a number of other things.